# The XAMPP data have mounted in the `/opt/lampp`, but under the `/opt` there is no `lampp` directory

Tags: macos, xampp

The XAMPP data have mounted in the `/opt/lampp`, but under the `/opt` there is no `lampp` directory.

```
$ ls
local
```

The directories:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It's location is`/Users/luowensxxx/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change something inside htdocs in the terminal, do not include the opt/lampp. it shows the root instead. try to open root ls. it will show all folders and file inside lampp. it works for me.